# Can't convert to HEX - TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found

Tags: python, python-2.7

The line `deviceToken = deviceToken.replace(' ','').decode('hex')` is crashing my script.
this is the device token: (with a few numbers changed)

`deviceToken = '9cdcb815 d93e11ce 52baaf6c 14e27cc8 31d5ce62 2e51ce6d f75692c2 3617cadb'`

The first push notification is sending out fine so I'm sure the device token is ok but after the first event I'm getting this error:

```
['"INBOX" (UNSEEN 12)'] 
Sent Push alert.
Got an event!
['"INBOX" (UNSEEN 13)']
Exception in thread Thread-4:Exception in thread Thread-4:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 483, in run
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
      File "server.py", line 111, in idle
        self.dosync()
      File "server.py", line 118, in dosync
        sendPushNotification(numUnseen)
      File "server.py", line 54, in sendPushNotification
        deviceToken = deviceToken.replace(' ','').decode('hex')
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
        output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
    TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

[Link to the script](https://github.com/gevermann/gmail-iphone-push/blob/master/server/server.py)

Comment: Show us the string you're trying to convert (although the error message is pretty self explanatory; you need all hex digits in the string and don't have that). (Are you copying your actual device token into the script, or trying it with "XXXXX XXXX..."?)

Comment: The device token is fine. I'm getting the first push notification to my iPhone. The error comes after the first event. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You're replacing the global deviceToken with its bytes, then trying to do it again the next time through the function. It's not repeatable.

Comment: Is there an easy fix for it? (Sorry, I'm an iOS developer with no knowledge in python)

Comment: Decode the token once at the global scope instead of inside the function?

Comment: I moved `deviceToken = deviceToken.replace(' ','').decode('hex')` just under the `deviceToken = '9cdcb815...` (that's the global scope?) and it's working now. Please write your comment in a form of an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 7):

Your device token is probably not what you think it is. Perhaps it has a newline or some other character that you can't see.

As a simple test:

```
>>> deviceToken = '9cdcb815 d93e11ce 52baaf6c 14e27cc8 31d5ce62 2e51ce6d f75692c2 3617cadb'
>>> deviceToken.replace(' ','')
'9cdcb815d93e11ce52baaf6c14e27cc831d5ce622e51ce6df75692c23617cadb'
>>> deviceToken.replace(' ','').decode('hex')
'\x9c\xdc\xb8\x15\xd9>\x11\xceR\xba\xafl\x14\xe2|\xc81\xd5\xceb.Q\xcem\xf7V\x92\xc26\x17\xca\xdb'
```

Comment: +1 for the idea ( I actually faced something very similar recently) but the problem was somewhere else.